# How to add a Custom Serializer to alter the Output of REST EXPORT

Tags: views, 8

To the Response/Output of REST EXPORT of a view, I want to add one extra row.

So I created a Custom Serializer in my module.
The path of the file is:

```
My_Module/src/Plugin/views/style/HindiCustomSerializer.php
```

Here I extended the `Serializer` Class from `core/modules/rest/src/Plugin/views/style/Serializer.php`

And I am trying to override the `render()` method in my custom serializer like this. I am copying the `render()` method from original Serializer and adding one extra line from my side.

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableDependencyInterface;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer;

/**
 * The style plugin for serialized output formats.
 *
 * Add and extra row to the output.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "hindi_custom_serializer",
 *   title = @Translation("Hindi Custom Serializer"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes views row data using the Serializer component."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class HindiCustomSerializer extends Serializer implements CacheableDependencyInterface{

  public function render() {
    $rows = [];
    // If the Data Entity row plugin is used, this will be an array of entities
    // which will pass through Serializer to one of the registered Normalizers,
    // which will transform it to arrays/scalars. If the Data field row plugin
    // is used, $rows will not contain objects and will pass directly to the
    // Encoder.
    foreach ($this->view->result as $row_index => $row) {
      $this->view->row_index = $row_index;
      $rows[] = $this->view->rowPlugin->render($row);
    }

    $rows[] = "JUST ADDING AN EXTRA ROW!!";
    unset($this->view->row_index);
    // Get the content type configured in the display or fallback to the
    // default.
    if ((empty($this->view->live_preview))) {
      $content_type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
    }
    else {
      $content_type = !empty($this->options['formats']) ? reset($this->options['formats']) : 'json';
    }
    return $this->serializer->serialize($rows, $content_type, ['views_style_plugin' => $this]);
  }

}
```

The option to choose the custom serializer **MyCustomSerializer** should be visible in **Format section of view settings**.

[image]

But its not displaying. Is there any step I am missing? Do I need to add some extra information regarding the serializer in `.info` file or any such steps needed ?

PS: If I add this line directly to the original Serializer code, I see the extra row coming in the response.

```
$rows[] = "JUST ADDING AN EXTRA ROW!!";
```

But of course that's not the correct way.

Comment: For what I'm seeing in your question droves me  that you forgot to add the proper @ViewStyle annotation check the `\Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer` annotation

Comment: What are the possible issues ?

Comment: Sorry I wrote to fast and stroke the Enter key without adding my actual comment :). Also don't forget to clear caches

Comment: thanks for comment. I added the annotations and updated the question. Still not getting it displayed.

Comment: You put it in the wrong place. I've updated your question with the annotation placed properly on the class not the method. Please test it that way and more information if the problem persist since this is a common solution and should work in almost all cases.

Comment: Another thing your plugin path... never use caps on your module's names. Could you add your plugin namespace? Also check that your module is being installed and is invoked properly for instance: implement hook_views_post_render and check is loaded.

Comment: After adding namespace and annotations in the correct place, its working. Thank you very much. Please add answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103674/discussion-between-sandesh-yadav-and-d70rr3s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin was missing the proper annotation (added now in the question). Views plugins use [Annotation Discovery](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/d8-plugin-discovery).

Adding something like the following solved the problem:

```
/**
 * My custom serializer
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "hindi_custom_serializer",
 *   title = @Translation("Hindi Custom Serializer"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes views row data using the Serializer component."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class HindiCustomSerializer extends Serializer {
  ....
}
```

Also worth noting that you don't need to include the `implements CacheableDependencyInterface` since is already declared by the `\Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer` plugin which you are extending from.